# Animation Node "Math node"

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

[image]

I am using Blender v2.78.4 and i am using animation nodes but when i am searching "Math node" .. its not showing. Please help

Comment: ...Maybe "Float Math" in your list there? What are you doing math on?

Answer (score 2):

Click Shift + A and go to "numbers" in the pop-up and then you will find "math" as a node there.

Answer (score 1):

When you searching "Math", you need to know, that where is several nodes in AN called "Math". One "Math" for numbers, one - for vectors, two - for rotation ets...

So, if in search box nodes will have name like they called, you will see in search box: *"Math" "Math" "Math" "Math"...*

So to understand which "Math" node you need, in search box you see the prefix of that "Math" node you need. So if you want to make operations with numbers choose "Float math", Want to sum 2 vectors - choose "Vector math". Operations with rotation - "Quaternion math" or "Euler math"